# How can I troubleshoot an Airport Express?

Tags: airport-express

I've had an Apple airport express router for about 4 years. I took it on a trip but when I got back home I've found that it's no longer working. I've restarted it, reset it to facotry settings, and tried to use Apple's "airport utility" but that doesn't get past the "joining wireless network" step (simply tells
me an error ocurred).  Anything else I can do here, or should I assume it's dead?

Comment: (Since this is almost a month ago: did you happen to solve it? Or meanwhile have some more info?)

Comment: if Arjan's solution doesn't help, it may just be dead.  i had a 5-yr-old Linksys go out on me recently.  similar troubleshooting steps, eventually i gave up and replaced it.  (we think it was killed by cat pee).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd temporarily connect the AirPort Express to your computer using an UTP (ethernet) cable. Then the AirPort Utility does not need to get a wireless connection to start the troubleshooting.

Comment: I didn't get a chance to test this since I wound up just tossing the Airport Express. However, it sounds like it'd work. :P  If it doesn't I guess people can vote it down and I'll un-accept it.